# Best way of balancing accounts (represented with integers) to near 0 on a single pass

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, logic

I've got an array of bank accounts that have a minimum monthly payment requirement and I'm trying to figure out the logic to get the optimal payment schedule. Here's the array structure:

```
array(4) {
  ["account_one"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["account"]=>
    string(21) "Account One"
    ["balance"]=>
    int(2500)
    ["minimum_payment"]=>
    int(1000)
  }
  ["account_two"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["account"]=>
    string(16) "Account Two"
    ["balance"]=>
    int(1500)
    ["minimum_payment"]=>
    int(500)
  }
  ["account_three"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["account"]=>
    string(10) "Account Three"
    ["balance"]=>
    int(3000)
    ["minimum_payment"]=>
    int(750)
  }
  ["account_four"]=>
  array(9) {
    ["account"]=>
    string(14) "Account Four"
    ["balance"]=>
    int(3000)
    ["minimum_payment"]=>
    int(750)
  }
}
```

In this example, the total amount of money in the accounts is 10000 and it needs to be moved between each account to meet the minimum payment requirement. The payment schedule also needs to be as efficient as possible, with the fewest number of payments to meet the requirements. This is a simple example, but in production we might have 15 or more accounts with varying minimum payment amounts.

What I've got so far isn't very much as I'm struggling to grasp the overall logic I need:

```
$accounts_by_amount (array of accounts sorted by balance high to low)
$accounts_reversed ($accounts_by_amount in reverse order)
$schedule = array()
foreach $accounts_by_amount as $account_a
    foreach $accounts_reversed as $account_b
        if $account_a['minimum_payment'] > $account_b['mininum_payment']
            // use higher minimum payment to reduce total payments needed
            $schedule_b[] = array(
              'from' => $account_a['account'],
              'to' => $account_b['account'],
              'amount' => $account_a['minimum_payment'],
            );
        else
            continue;

    if $schedule_b
        $schedule += $schedule_b
    else
        continue
```

This doesn't work, obviously, but I think I might be making this overly complex with the loop within a loop. I'm not looking for somebody to actually write code for me, more to tell me how dumb I'm being with the logic and a rough idea of how to pull this schedule together with the minimum number of payments.

Comment: I read your question several times and it still isn't at all clear what you are trying to figure out/accomplish. All of the account balances in your example have enough to cover the minimum payment for each account.

Comment: Dave, it's maybe a bad example, as sometimes there won't be enough in the balance to make the payment until money has been transferred into the account from another. There's 10k total split amongst the accounts, and I need a payment schedule that moves the money between each account to hit the minimum payment. I'll try and reword the original question.

Comment: I'm also confused.  You talk about a schedule with varying payments, but I see no provision for describing those payments and variations, and no treatment of a time-based process.  Also, if there is no time-based input, then the time factor is immaterial: you need to cover the *total* of all payments for each account.  Please supply clear examples and problem cases for input and output.

Comment: We will need time associations with the array items, so something like payment due date. If the payment due date is the same for all of them it's even better. I think what you're trying to do is minimum number of transfers between N accounts so you meet their min payment values. Also knowing if our total money will be always bigger than what needs to be paid would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding the scheduling logic, I wrote something like this to transfer and balance the amounts between accounts. Hope this helps. This is in JavaScript / I'll leave it up to you to try it out with PHP.

Basically we calculate the workable balances, sort the workable balances from high to low and start iterating from the start and the end while balancing the accounts. This is also not the minimum number of transfers that you could do, but if you re-compute the best available account after every iteration you could get that.

It would execute at O(n) at the worst case computation-wise, in the real worst case scenario you wouldn't have enough money in your best account which would make it skip the while loop. But that means you'd have real problems, not big O notation.

```
let accounts = [
    { id: 2, balance: 6000, minpay: 4000 },
    { id: 1, balance: 5000, minpay: 2000 },
    { id: 3, balance: 4000, minpay: 4000 },
    { id: 4, balance: 4000, minpay: 5000 },
    { id: 6, balance: 3000, minpay: 6000 },
    { id: 5, balance: 3000, minpay: 5000 }
];

// create a map of workable balances.
let workableBalance = accounts.map(v => {
    return {
        id: v.id,
        value: v.balance - v.minpay
    }
}).sort((a,b) => {return b.value-a.value}); // sort descending;

let cursorFromBeginning = 0;
let cursorFromEnd = workableBalance.length - 1;

if (workableBalance[cursorFromEnd].value > 0) {
    console.log('All accounts have sufficient money in them.');
    return; // terminate.
}

if (workableBalance[cursorFromBeginning].value < 0) {
    console.log(`No way that we'll balance the accounts. The best account is in negatives.`);
    return; // terminate.
}

console.log('Present state of things: ', workableBalance);

while(cursorFromBeginning < cursorFromEnd) {
    // Get the balance from least available account.
    // Validate that the worst account actually needs money.
    let worstAccount = workableBalance[cursorFromEnd];
    if (worstAccount.value >= 0) {
        console.log(`All good! We're balanced`, workableBalance);
        return;
    }

    let bestAccount = workableBalance[cursorFromBeginning];
    if (bestAccount.value == 0) {
        cursorFromBeginning++;
        continue;
    }

    // Can this account single-handedly balance the next worst account?
    if (bestAccount.value >= Math.abs(worstAccount.value)) {
        // Balance the account.
        console.log(`Moving $${bestAccount.value} from account ${bestAccount.id} to ${worstAccount.id} - balancing the whole account.`);
        bestAccount.value += worstAccount.value;
        worstAccount.value = 0;
        cursorFromEnd--;
    }
    else {
        // Balance as much as we can.
        console.log(`Moving $${bestAccount.value} from account ${bestAccount.id} to ${worstAccount.id} - balancing the account partially.`);
        bestAccount.value = 0;
        worstAccount.value += bestAccount.value;
        cursorFromBeginning++;
    }
}


console.log('Things after some magic: ', workableBalance);
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. There's no due date, so this works. I'll have a look at trying to get something similar into PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear! I'd appreciate the green tick :)